# Averaged matrix exponential inverse

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, matrix-exponential, integral-operators

Let $H$ be a given symmetric matrix, i.e., $H\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}_{\rm sym}$, $d\geq1$. The operator $T$ is given by
$$TX=\int_0^1e^{(1-s)H}Xe^{sH}\mathrm{d}s,\qquad X\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}_{\rm sym}.$$
This is a fourth order tensor, that is also positive definite:
$$TX\cdot X=\int_0^1|e^{\frac{1-s}2H}Xe^{\frac{s}2H}|^2\mathrm{d}s,$$
so $T^{-1}$ exists. **Can we find an explicit formula for $T^{-1}$?**

Based on the scalar case, where $TX=e^HX$ and $T^{-1}X=e^{-H}X$, I have tried to compute
$$\int_0^1e^{-(1-t)H}\int_0^1e^{(1-s)H}Xe^{sH}\mathrm{d}s\,e^{-tH}\mathrm{d}t=\ldots=\int_0^1(1-u)(e^{uH}Xe^{-uH}+e^{-uH}Xe^{uH})\mathrm{d}u,$$
which however does not seem to evaluate to $X$.

Comment: You can compute the integral in a basis where $H$ is diagonal.

Comment: I can compute it whenever $X$ and $H$ commute (in particular if $H$ is diagonal), but how does it help with the general case?

Comment: If $A, B$ are diagonal matrices, then $A X B = (a_{ii} x_{ij} b_{jj})_{ij}$. You can integrate every coefficient. Then you will easily see the inverse of the operator $T$.

Comment: I agree that if $H$ is diagonal it is easy, but I don't see the general case.

Comment: Write $H = P^T D P$ where $D$ is diagonal and $P^T P = I$. Similarly write $X = P^T Y P$. Then $e^{(1-s)H} X e^{s H} = P^T e^{(1-s)D}Ye^{s D} P$.

Comment: I now see what you mean...